# Lost selection after binding new items to select

Tags: angular

I am having an issue for select element on Angular 2.
I created 2 examples on 2 different versions of Angular2 but same behaviour:

- Version 2.0.0-rc.1:

  [plnkr.co/edit/Z28xFwINRLZWJYS4z4zi?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z28xFwINRLZWJYS4z4zi?p=preview)
- Version 2.0.2:

  [plnkr.co/edit/UW7K1rGOzYcIjG4f3KTI?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/UW7K1rGOzYcIjG4f3KTI?p=preview)

Please follow steps: change selected from '2' to '1' -> click button 'Test' ->

- Version 2.0.0-rc.1 -> it's ok
- Version 2.0.2 -> it's fail, lost selection

These are codes to expose this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="value">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item.value">
        {{item.text}}
    </option>
</select>
<button type="button" (click)="test()">Test</button>
    `
})
export class App {

  items: any[];
    value: any;

  constructor() {
    this.items = [
            { text: '1', value: 1 },
            { text: '2', value: 2 }
        ];
        this.value = this.items[1].value;
  }

  test() {
    this.value = this.items[0].value;
        this.items = [
            { text: '1', value: 1 },
            { text: '2', value: 2 },
            { text: '3', value: 3 }
        ];

    }

}
```

I wonder version 2.0.2 got bug? How to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Please with your best judgement try to include some snippets of your code that you think is causing the problem you have. There's a reason StackOverflow does not allow links to plnkr without code blocks.

Comment: @HarryNinh: I appended some codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click button `Test` your `[ngModel]` property remains the same as previous value.
Moving

```
this.value = this.items[0].value;
```

to the end of the `test()` will also not help because

```
1 === 1
```

and method `isPropertyUpdated` within `ngOnChanges` in `NgModel` directive will return false.

So i think you have to change your declaration as mentioned in angular2 specification

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.2/modules/%40angular/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts#L581-L659

like:

```
[ngValue]="item"
```

and in component:

```
constructor() {
  this.items = [
    { text: '1', value: 1 },
    { text: '2', value: 2 }
  ];
  this.value = this.items[1];
}

test() {
  this.items = [
    { text: '1', value: 1 },
    { text: '2', value: 2 },
    { text: '3', value: 3 }
  ];
  this.value = this.items[0];
}
```

In js `{} !== {}`

This will help you to avoid strange behavior by using `select[ngModel]`

http://plnkr.co/edit/vdyqnwR6HpqHD8FoqwAA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is because you create a new array. `[ngValue]` compares object identity not data content. If it gets a different object instance, it doesn't consider it the same and doesn't show it as selected.

Either update `value` in `test()` to reflect the new selection or don't create a new array but instead just modify the previously created one.

Actually moving

```
this.value = this.items[0].value;
```

to the end of the `test()` function would fix your problem.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JwUAEPHtniHYyMk70s7P?p=preview)

Comment: Not workings, please recheck, you replace this.items= with  this.items.push= ? What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save the last change. It should work now.

Comment: Also not working, please follow my steps, selection also lost :(

Comment: No idea what you mean with "lost". `this.value = this.items[0].value;` sets the selection to the first element and that is what the plunker does when `[test]` is clicked.

Comment: 'Selection lost' means that text displays on select tag is empty,

Comment: Can't reproduce. For me it changes from `2` to `1` when I click `[test]`. Can you please try close and reopen the Plunker link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126884/discussion-between-leo-vo-and-gunter-zochbauer).